# PersistenceUnitInfo implementation in EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

EntityManagerFactory can be created without a persistence unit xml using

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider {
 public EntityManagerFactory createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info,
                                                                    java.util.Map properties)
    }
```

but what is the implementation class of javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo in eclipselink

Answer (score 5):

I am struggling on this problem too. I think that a `PersistenceUnitInfo` must be provided by the container(i.e. Application Server). It means that Eclipselink do not create one itself. If you are using Spring ORM, it uses a `DefaultPersistenceUnitManager` and call its `obtainPersistenceUnitInfo(String unitName)` method to get a instance of `PersistenceUnitInfo`. The unitName must be defined in `persistence.xml`. This means that you still needs an xml file.

By digging into the source code of Spring ORM, I found that Spring provides several implementations of `PersistenceUnitInfo`. In fact they are generally a Java Bean. You may be interested in `SmartPersistenceInfo`, `MutablePersistenceInfo` and `SpringPersistenceUnitInfo`. View them on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit).

EDIT:

I found the implementation of Eclipselink: It's `SEPersistenceUnitInfo` in `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment`. Also found the method that reads every persistence unit in the configuration xml file.

```
    public static Set<SEPersistenceUnitInfo> getPersistenceUnits(ClassLoader loader, Map m, List<URL> jarFileUrls) {
    String descriptorPath = (String) m.get(PersistenceUnitProperties.ECLIPSELINK_PERSISTENCE_XML);
    if(descriptorPath == null) {
        descriptorPath = System.getProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.ECLIPSELINK_PERSISTENCE_XML, PersistenceUnitProperties.ECLIPSELINK_PERSISTENCE_XML_DEFAULT);
    }
    Set<Archive> archives = findPersistenceArchives(loader, descriptorPath, jarFileUrls);
    Set<SEPersistenceUnitInfo> puInfos = new HashSet();
    try {
        for(Archive archive : archives) {
            List<SEPersistenceUnitInfo> puInfosFromArchive = getPersistenceUnits(archive, loader);
            puInfos.addAll(puInfosFromArchive);
        }
    } finally {
        for(Archive archive : archives) {
            archive.close();
        }
    }
    return puInfos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java EE platform spec 6 says : the container is responsible for finding persistence.xml condensing the information into PersistenceUnitInfo and supplying that with a call to createContainerEntityManagerFactory.

Answer (score 0):

PersistenceUnitInfo is defined by the Spec, refer to the JPA spec code or JavaDoc for its implementation.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html

Comment: Not clear about, how to create instance of PersistenceUnitInfo ? JPA spec define that it is implemented by container . Is there any example code about to create entitymanager without persistence xml using `createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info,java.util.Map properties)`

Comment: You need to define your own class that implements the interface.

Comment: May you define small code example snippet to create entitymanager without persistence xml using `createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info,java.util.Map properties)`